# Integrate Prolog in C program

Tags: c++, c, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I want to write a main program in C++ and the program will generate facts **dynamically** to build up a knowledge base, then the program can call rules defined in some `.pl` files and get the results. For example,
main.c

```
int main()
{
   //generate facts like 
    // blue(car), red(bike), etc
    // do queries
    PL_call( "consult( 'pred.pl' )" );
    ...
    PL_call(goal_term, NULL);
}
```

pred.pl

```
whatisblue(X) :- blue(X).
whatisred(X) :- red(X).
```

How can I do it?

I read the swi-prolog manual on C interface but only see how to call C module in Prolog or call Prolog in C, I do not see how to mix predicates defined both in C and Prolog. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'mix'? Which is the main language? C++ as I understand. So just call the predicates that are building your database (`assertz` and company), and then call your logic.

Comment: Main language is C++. Some predicates (facts) will be created in C++, but querying rules are defined in Prolog file. And I want to do the query (calling prolog) in the C++ based on the facts created in C++. You mean when I create the facts, I call the built-in `assertz`, etc?  Does it support building large knowledge base with many facts? Thanks.

Comment: `assertz` is just adding a fact to the end of a database. So depending on the memory available it can build up an arbitrary size database.

Comment: Yes. It looks like what I need. I am rather new to Prolog.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you assert facts, they are only in memory. If you want to save them, you need to write your facts out to a file using Prolog's file I/O predicates.

Answer (score 0):

A detailed answer is out of my possibilities now, but overall, the answer to your question is 'yes'.

Just, in C++, use the C++ interface. It's far easier than C. So use PlCall, PlTermv etc...

The problem is to correctly **bind** the variables, before and after PlCall(s), so you can exchange values with Prolog.

To ease the construction of structured values, for instance, take a look to [these macros](https://github.com/CapelliC/loqt/blob/master/pqConsole/PREDICATE.h) comments, predicate0, predicate1, ... and structure1,structure2,..., or consider

```
#define unary(X) PlTerm X; PlCompound X ## _t(#X, X);
```

that allows to put in [code](https://github.com/CapelliC/loqt/blob/master/pqSource/pqTextAttributes.cpp)

```
attrs2format_t::const_iterator p = attrs2format.find(k);
if (p == attrs2format.end()) {
    // attributes documented here:
    // http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prolog_colour:syntax_colour/2

    unary(colour)
    unary(background)
    unary(bold)
    unary(underline)

    // use unification to match list' elements
    PlTail attrs(attr_list);
    PlTerm attr;
...
```

You can find [here](http://prolog-in-the-wild.blogspot.it/) some general note about interfacing SWI-Prolog